# Trying to get email from the database based on username

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, minecraft

I'm trying to get the users email, but I don't know how to get the row that their account is on without referencing the username, and if I do that, then I cannot assign the email to the variable, but the username. If emails aren't unique I cannot simply search for the email, so what can I do to assign the email variable to the email that is correlated with the username that is already assigned.

Here is the function I am using, if you need any more information please ask!

```
 function getEmail() {


        $sql = "SELECT username FROM TripexLogin WHERE username = '" . $_SESSION['username'] . "' LIMIT 1";
    $query = mysql_query($sql) or trigger_error("Query Failed: " . mysql_error());

    // If one row was returned, the user was logged in!
    if (mysql_num_rows($query) == 1) {
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
                $_SESSION['email'] = $row['email'];

        }
}
```

Comment: You're using deprecated `mysql_*` functions. You should switch to `mysqli_*` or `PDO`.

Comment: Would that cause it not to work? I am worried about functionality, not effectiveness right now.

Comment: Just to clarify, is it that only getEmail doesn't work right? Does createAccount and validateUser work?

Comment: Everything works, except getEmail. I am able to reference the accounts username using $_SESSION['username'] I am wanting to do that with any field (mainly email one) connected to that users row on the database

Comment: validate and createaccount do work, as does loggedIn()

Comment: time to var_dump and http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: Can you elaborate how to do that?

Comment: use `var_dump();` here and there and it does accept arguments. I.e.: `var_dump($var);` and add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything in all files.

Comment: Okay, but just so you all know, I am not great with php and that code is likely to be wrong on getEmail() function

Comment: Here is a picture offall the errors.
http://prntscr.com/a5jf0r

Comment: that's why we try to help and giving you tools to check for errors and to see what is being passed or not. That's where doing echos and `var_dump();` come in handy, as does viewing your HTML source.

Comment: It says I have an undefined variable, which is what I'm trying to define based on the information gathered from the database.

Comment: judging by the errors in your printcap, which you should have pasted as text in your question, you did not assign anything to the `$pEmail` variable or `$sOutputs` variable. Which the latter seems to reside inside another file. This could also be a variable scope issue. check all your files and paths, includes etc. there isn't much else I can say here, but try to make those as global or passed through your function. Good luck, *cheers*

Comment: So does anyone know how I can define the variable based on the information gathered from the database that correlates with the username of the authenticated user?

Comment: I updated the code, this seems to be more accurate to a working version, but It still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know nothing about Minecraft but selecting the *username* from a table given that very same username as search key doesn't make sense to me. So I'm guessing the statement should be

```
select EMAIL from TripexLogin where username=?
```

instead of

```
select USERNAME from TripexLogin where username=?
```